# $\sigma \text{-algebras}$ inclusion

Tags: measure-theory

Attempt to show that $A\subset B \implies \sigma(A)\subset \sigma(B)$. Is it correct?

Let $A\subset B$. $\sigma(B)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $B$ so we have $B\subset \sigma(B)$. Suppose that $\sigma(B)\subset \sigma(A)$. This contradicts the fact that $\sigma(A)$ is smallest. Hence $\sigma(A)\subset \sigma(B)$.

**FIX**

$A\subset B \subset \sigma(B)$ and $\sigma(A) = \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ for $\sigma$-algebras $A_i$ containing $A$. In particular $A_j=\sigma(B)$ for some $j$. Hence $\sigma(A)\subset \sigma(B)$.

Comment: Do you use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ the same way?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yes.

Comment: Then you have to allow for $A=B$, which contradicts your, almost correct, argument.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker using strict $\subset$ fixes it, right?

Comment: Yes, but you do not get a contradiction. You have shown that $A\subseteq\sigma(A)$ and $A\subseteq\sigma(B)$. By definition, $\sigma(A)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$, so $\sigma(A)\subseteq\sigma(B)$.

Comment: The contradiction is that $\sigma(B)$ is smaller than $\sigma(A)$ by my assumption. So my assumption is absurd.

Comment: But that $\sigma(B)$ is not smaller than $\sigma(A)$ is not the same thing as $\sigma(A)\subseteq\sigma(B)$.

Comment: I see, so you are saying that: not $A\subset B$ is not the same as $B \subset A$?

Comment: Exactly. If $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$ neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: How about now? Thanks for the time.

Comment: Perfect. I would maybe make the first step more explicit though by writing "$A\subset B\subset \sigma(B)$".

Answer (score 1):

Your fix looks good, but can be made simpler. $A\subseteq B\subseteq\sigma(B),$ so $\sigma(B)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$. The smallest such $\sigma$-algebra is $\sigma(A),$ meaning in particular that $$\sigma(A)\subseteq\sigma(B).$$